# Find all records where one-to-many join table satisfies one condition, but not another condition

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to get all Foos which have at least one Bar with type "Apple", but also do NOT have a Bar with type "Orange" in the schema:

```
Foo
----
id

Bar
----
id
foo_id
type
```

If my data were this:

```
Foos
----
| id |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |

Bars
----
| id | foo_id | type   |
| 1  | 1      | Apple  |
| 2  | 1      | Orange |
| 3  | 3      | Apple  |
```

This query would return only Foo with ID=3, since 1 has an Apple but also an Orange, and 2 has no Orange but also has no Apple.

Also, I will tag this post with Rails because an ActiveRecord solution would be preferred but isn't necessary.

Comment: Are `Foo` and `Bar` related classes?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes, Foo has many Bars (as shown by `foo_id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is probably best to do this with subqueries.  SQL:

```
Foo.find_by_sql("SELECT f.* FROM foo f WHERE 
  f.id IN (SELECT foo_id FROM bar x WHERE x.type='Apple') AND
  f.id NOT IN (SELECT foo_id FROM bar WHERE x.type='Orange')")
```

ARel:

```
Foo.where(id: Bar.select("foo_id").where(type: 'Apple'))
   .where.not(id: Bar.select("foo_id").where(type: 'Orange'))
```

I tested both ways in my own schema so I apologize in advance for any typos converting to your domain.

Comment: Sure Logan glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql

```
SELECT foo_id FROM test.bars GROUP BY foo_id  HAVING SUM(IF(type = 'Apple',1,0)) > 0 AND SUM(IF(type = 'Orange',1,0)) = 0 ;
```

or same in ActiveRecord:

```
bars.group(:foo_id).having('SUM(IF(type = "Apple",1,0)) > ?',0).having('SUM(IF(type = "Orange",1,0)) = ?', 0)
```

Comment: Won't the second query return a collection of `Bar`s, not `Foo`s?